# select the negative of a SPARQL query

Tags: sparql

Is possible to select the "negative" of a sparql query?

For instance, consider the following RDF data, query and desired result:

#### knowledge base:

```
@prefix gr:<http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#>.
@prefix rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>.

:prod_A :hasProp :propA.
:prod_B :hasProp :propB.
   :propB rdfs:label "Hello".
:prod_C :hasProp :propC.
:prod_D :hasProp :propD.
```

#### Imaginary Query:

```sql
PREFIX gr:<http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#>

SELECT ?prod WHERE 
   { !( 
      ?prod ?p ?o.
      ?o ?p2 ?o2.
   ) }
```

#### Ideal Result:

```
| ?prod   |
|---------|
| :prod_A | 
| :prod_C | 
| :prod_D |
```

is there a way through? (i need it for a `delete`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `MINUS` is what you are looking for:

```sql
PREFIX gr:<http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#>

SELECT ?prod WHERE 
{
  ?prod ?p ?o.
  MINUS { ?o ?p2 ?o2 }
}
```

It takes the things matched by the left hand side (`?prod ?p ?o`) and removes any that correspond to items matched by the `MINUS` pattern.

Note this doesn't give your desired answer because the `?prod ?p ?o` pattern matches everything including the linked property (`:propB rdfs:label "Hello"`) that you aren't interested in for your results

To get your desired answer you need to make the first part of the query more specific like so:

```sql
PREFIX :<http://example.org/>
PREFIX gr:<http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#>

SELECT ?prod WHERE 
{
  ?prod :hasProp ?o.
  MINUS { ?o ?p2 ?o2 }
}
```

Here I changed the `?p` variable to be the `:hasProp` constant instead.  With this query I get your desired answer.

**NB** - You didn't define the empty prefix in your example so I invented one to make the query valid and so I could test that it worked

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use `FILTER NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT ?prod WHERE 
{
  ?prod :hasProp ?o.
  FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?o rdfs:label "Hello". }
}
```

which does the first `?prod :hasProp ?o.` then checks whether ?o causes `?o rdfs:label "Hello"` to match.  Use the form you find easiest to understand.